# XPages Design Refresh

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a question regarding the design refresh/replace mechanism. Are XPages and Custom-Controls replicated?

In the [Documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_REFRESHING_A_DESIGN.html?lang=en) they are not listed as component. However, in the confirmation dialog they are listed:

[image]

If not, how can I distribute XPages between different database?

Comment: Be aware of build process - to replicate/refresh/replace custom control does not mean it will work - its class file is important (and yes, it is also the design element). [This trick](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/view-of-design-elements.htm) helped me a LOT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, XPages and Custom Controls are part of design refresh/replace mechanism. In general all design elements visible in Designer/Applications are part of it.

You are right, those design elements are not listed in documentation ([neither in version 9](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_REFRESHING_A_DESIGN.html)) but should be.

Comment: It's worth noting that XPages and Custom Controls are not in either list. Also, nor are JAR design elements. Bear in mind that JAR design elements may not get updated in 8.5.3. I think it's more stable in 9.0.x.

Comment: And: even files & folders stored in the WebContent folder are replicated i.e. part of the design itself and will be used when refreshing the design of a database.

Comment: How about translation property files?

Comment: Yes, the translation properties files in XPages folder get refreshed/replaced too.

Comment: I make a lot of Java Design elements in DDE.  Those will refresh just fine to other databases.